# Why is Stream.CopyTo not writing directly to a file?

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

This action block is connected to a transform block with the signature`var getStream = new TransformBlock<FileChunk, Tuple<Task<HttpResponseMessage>, FileChunk>>` however, the stream is not writing directly to the file provided. For some reason, I think that it is still being cached to memory. The Task is the tuple is initalized as `client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);`

```
var writeStream = new ActionBlock<Tuple<Task<HttpResponseMessage>, FileChunk>>(async task =>
{
    using (var streamToRead = await task.Item1.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (var fileToWriteTo = File.Open(task.Item2._tempfilename,
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            await task.Item1.Result.Content.CopyToAsync(fileToWriteTo).ContinueWith(task1 =>
            {
                var s = new FileChunk();
                Interlocked.Add(ref TasksDone, 1);
                asyncTasks.TryDequeue(out s);
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Current);
        }
    }
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    BoundedCapacity = Environment.ProcessorCount, // Cap the item count
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, // Parallelize on all cores
});
```

Any advice on how I can fix this? Also, I am assuming that it is caching to memory first because the file size does not update or increase on refresh, rather all at once.

Comment: What's going on with the task continuation? Particularly the `out s` - that's not going anywhere.

Comment: It's also a little weird that you've got a `ConcurrentQueue<FileChunk>` called `asyncTasks`.

Comment: I would love to see a [mcve] of what you're doing?

Comment: @Enigmativity it's not really supposed to go anywhere. I'm using a custom ConcurrentQueue for calling events on Enqueue and TryDequeue. You can see exactly what I'm using this for on my [github repo](https://github.com/gregyjames/OctaneDownloader)

Comment: Ideally you should post enough detail in your question to be able to see what's going on. One thing I saw when I had a quick look at your code in the repo is the use of `try` `catch (Exception ex) { .. }` code throughout. That's just great way of swallowing errors. Who knows if that's part of this problem. You should remove it all and only catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: Try change your HttpCompletionOption on SendAsync to`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. This will allow you to stream the response content directly from the socket as soon as the headers are available, rather than buffering the response to memory before you can access it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to detach the artificial `ContinueWith` continuation, and `await` directly the `CopyToAsync` operation. With your current setup you'll get no information if something goes wring, because in case of an exception the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` will cause the continuation to become cancelled, and the TPL Dataflow blocks ignore `OperationCanceledException`s.

Here is my suggestion:

```
var writeStream = new ActionBlock<Tuple<Task<HttpResponseMessage>, FileChunk>>(async task =>
{
    using (var streamToRead = await task.Item1.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (var fileToWriteTo = File.Open(task.Item2._tempfilename,
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            await task.Item1.Result.Content.CopyToAsync(fileToWriteTo);
        }
        Interlocked.Add(ref TasksDone, 1);
        asyncTasks.TryDequeue(out var s);
    }
});
```

I also suggest to consider replacing the `Tuple` with `ValueTuple`, in order to get a [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) and prevent redundant allocations:

```
var writeStream = new ActionBlock<(Task<HttpResponseMessage>, FileChunk)>(async task =>
```

Finally I should note that I am skeptical about the performance characteristics of a procedure that tries to write multiple files in the same physical disk concurrently.